# Wrapping the content between the header and the footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a complete noob in css, and I actually decided to do a bit of front-end to discover the joys of the css. And I must say that I am a bit lost. I have something that has been asked thousands of times, but it looks like there are a lot of different ways of doing what I want.

[image]

I am using angular.js for the bindings and bootstrap for the design (to ease design problems). I want to have a fixed header, a fixed footer, and between those 2, my content, which can be a caroussel, background-images, ...
I was having trouble for example to put caroussel taking the full height and width between the header and the footer, but I found examples like the following : http://www.bootply.com/N32yoVoWVI# where people define a wrapper to wrap the content.

What I don't really get is that usually, they define a padding for the wrapper which corresponds to the height of the header, so the image doesn't go on your header/footer.

What happens if I am on a mobile device? And that my logo bar in the header is smaller? Then the height of my header isn't the same. Should I use in that case the media-queries? To define the behaviour for the different screen sizes?

I feel like I am not being really clear and that I am a bit lost, so to resume, what would be the best way of defining the css of my page so that all the content is wrapped between the header and the footer (if an image is too big, it's resized, don't allow the scrolling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking a lot of different things but I will give it a shot to help you out.

What I am usually using for this kind of design is the following structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header-row">
   <div class="header">
     header content
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-row">
   <div class="content">
     content
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-row">
   <div class="footer">
     footer content
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.header-row,
.footer-row {
  display:table-row;
  height:1px;
}
.content-row {
  display:table-row;
  height:100%;
}
.header,
.footer,
.content {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

What the above code does is this: the wrapper covers the whole screen; the rows divide the table **in analogy to their heights**, so by using 1px height for the header and footer rows and 100% for the content, the header and footer rows stretch to fit their content, while the rest of the screen is left for the content. Also since tables are flexible, if the content exceeds the screen height it will simply stretch the parent container as well.

The above solution will get rid of all of the other problems you mentioned in your question - the mobile logo dimensions might have to be changed using media queries but you won't have to worry about the general layout.

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pdczopkk/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Shouldn't I add an attribute to fix my header and footer so they are always wrapped to the bottom and the top?

Comment: You don't need anything more, just having table:row with 1px should do it.

Comment: There must be something I didn't  understand, sorry for that. If I take your code, when I launch it in an html page, I have the 3 parts - header - content - footer that are following each other, but if the content is small, then the footer will be big. Is that the normal behaviour then? I'd like my header and footer to be fixed at the top and bottom with a fixed height

Comment: The html and body must also have 100% width and height, I thought this was obvious - just added a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: right, I forgot about that, my bad -_-' thanks a lot!

Comment: I have another question : let's say I have a content that is too big, is there a way to prevent the scrolling?

Comment: I think I didn't explain it well : let's say I have a caroussel with images that can be bigger than the content size, is there a way to wrap it between the header and the footer (so you don't have to scroll?). When it's too big, you cut a part of the image, and if it's too small, you zoom on it

Comment: well I can't design it for you! Sorry